# Concating String Array with semicolons

Tags: c#, string

It is a pattern that occurs quite often in one part of our Framework.
Given an Array of Strings, we have to concat all of them, seperated by Semicolons.

I´d like to know in which elegant way it can be done.
I`ve seen some variations across our codebase, and always, when i have to do this, i have to rethink again.

My current pattern is this:

```
String[] values = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"};
String concat = String.Empty;
foreach(String s in values)
{
   if(String.IsEmptyOrNullString(s) == false)
       concat + = ", ";
   concat += s;
}
```

What negs me is the if statement, i could insert the first item before the loop and start with a for loop, starting at index 1, but this doesn´t increase the readability.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: `if (!String.IsEmptyOrNullString(s))` would make it more readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `string.Join()`:

```
String[] values = new String[] {"a","b","c","d"};
var concat = string.Join(", ", values);
```

This will result in something looking like this:

> a, b, c, d

Comment: +1, although no need to assign `concat` with `Empty` first, just initialize it from the return from `Join`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, You're right, I just copied his code snippet and modified it. Forgot to remove that part, thanks for spotting it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var result = string.Join(",", values.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)));
```